# Using JUnit/Mockito to confirm that java.util.Timer.schedule() does what is expected?

Tags: java, junit, timer, mockito

I've seen rather a lot of posts about time-based testing techniques in JUnit/Mockito but there seem to be so many considerations that I've become confused about how I should think of my own code under test - and how/what exactly I should test.

My code under test is as follows:

```
class ClassUnderTest {
    Clock clock; // Thought this might be a useful DI, but not sure how...
    String delayString;
    Timer timer;

    public ClassUnderTest(String delayString, Clock clock) {
        this.clock = clock;
        this.delayString = delayString;
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ChronoUnit unit = parseDelayStringToGetUnit(); // Implementation not shown here
        Integer amountOfTime = parseDelayStringToGetAmount(); // Implementation not shown here
        long delay = calculateDelay(unit, amountOfTime); // Implementation not show here
        timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                taskToRun();
            }
        }, delay);
    }

    private void taskToRun() {
        // Does something after a delay
        // Happy to amend signature to take params or return a value ...
    }
}
```

It is admittedly very cut down but I wanted to cut through the unimportant stuff. It's basic function, when instantiated, is to call taskToRun() but only after parsing another string that's passed and which can be deserialised to a ChronoUnit and associated amount. There's only likely to be a limited number of delay lengths passed in, but they could range from 15 minutes to 8 hours.

I've read that I shouldn't need to test the timer itself, but I still feel that my test method should confirm that taskToRun() does indeed run eventually but not before the desired delay has expired. I thought that passing in a java.time.Clock as a dependency injection would help time-based testing, but at the moment I cannot see how (here) and clearly it isn't used for anything (yet).

Is what I want to test correct in principle and, if so, how do I go about doing it ?

EDIT:

Apologies. Just realised that the delayString also includes 'epochStart', an instant in time from when the delay should begin. The current calculation of the primitive 'delay' would instead calculate:

instantWhenDelayExpires = epochStart + (amount of ChronoUnit)

and the timer would then schedule using the instantWhenDelayExpires rather than an amount of delay.

I don't think this particularly complicates my question though ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I still feel that my test method should confirm that taskToRun()
>   does indeed run eventually but not before the desired delay has   expired

Indeed and in order to validate that why don't you rely on 
`Timer.schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)` that specifies the delay ?
In this way you could add a constructor in `ClassUnderTest`  for your test that accepts a `Timer` and you could mock it during the unit test. 
To assert that the `Timer` does what it is designed to do, you have just to verify that the mock was invoked with the correct parameters and especially the delay parameter.

```
@Mock
Timer mockedTimer;

@Test
void constructor(){
   long expectedDelay = ...;
   ClassUnderTest objectUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest(..., mockedTimer);
   Mockito.verify(mockedTimer).schedule(Mockito.any(),  expectedDelay);
}
```

Comment: Ha, thanks for the snippet, was just about to ask for that - you read my mind! Having little expertise in unit testing & TDD, I need to read more about Mockito but I do get your explanation - thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a bean in your application config,

```
@Bean
public Timer timer()
{
    return new Timer();
}
```

autowired that bean into the class,

```
@Autowired
private Timer _timer;
```

and mock that bean in your test class,

```
@MockBean
private Timer _timer;
```

Then you can capture the task that goes into the timer and verify the run task does what you want it to.

```
ArgumentCaptor<TimerTask> timerCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(TimerTask.class);
    Mockito.verify(_timer, Mockito.times(1))
            .scheduleAtFixedRate(timerCaptor.capture(), Mockito.anyLong(), Mockito.anyLong());

    TimerTask timerTask = timerCaptor.getValue();
    Assertions.assertNotNull(timerTask);

    // assuming the time runs the task
    timerTask.run();

    // verify methods inside run task are invoked...
```